# error: indirection requires pointer operand

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following functions, an initializeHeap function which takes in no arguments and outputs a Heap struct which I have defined. And an insertNode function which takes in a pointer to a heap struct and the number to be added to the heap. I call them in the main function as such:

```
h = initializeHeap();
Heap *p = *h;
insertNode(p,5);
insertNode(p,7);
insertNode(p,3);
insertNode(p,2);
```

I get this error when trying to do this:

```
error: indirection requires pointer operand
```

Any ideas? I can post more code if needed.

The struct Heap and function initializeHeap() are as follows:

```
typedef struct node{
    int data;
}Node;

typedef struct heap{
    int size;
    Node *dataArray;
}Heap;

Heap initializeHeap(){
    Heap heap;
    heap.size = 0;
    return heap;
}
```

Comment: What is the declaration of `initializeHeap`? More specifically, what is it declared to return?

Comment: So how is `h` defined, please?

Comment: An unrelated tip: If you have a structure with pointers in it, then it's usually a good idea to initialize the pointer to `NULL`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change:

```
Heap *p = *h;
```

to

```
Heap *p = &h;
```

`h` is a `Heap` structure object, use `&` operator to get a pointer to the structure object.